# Use a fallback datasource for Hibernate in Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, datasource

We are working on a Spring based Web application where the key to the business is high availability. Hibernate is the ORM and MySQL is the DB that is used. Our architecture forces us to have the following mechanism.

- The Webapp first tries to connect to the primary MySQL server.
- If that fails, it connects to the Secondary MySQL server, which is mostly out of sync with the data.
- The webapp needs to know which MySQL Server it is connected to, since we want to notify the user when he is using the secondary server.
- As soon as the connection re-establishes with the primary, the connected has to be switched from secondary to primary.

I am stuck at the very first phase. I am unable find out how to direct Spring/Hibernate to use multiple DB Servers.

Here is the current config file (removing the unwanted stuff):

```
 <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smartshop" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/primarydb" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1200000" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="5" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor"
        name="openSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="flushMode">
            <bean
                id="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.FLUSH_AUTO"
                class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
                <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Is there a way to define Spring to connect to a backup datasource when the primary datasource is inaccessible?

Comment: *Maybe* this will be useful: http://ha-jdbc.sourceforge.net

Comment: Doesn't appear to be serving my purpose :(

Answer (score 1):

if you configure your datasource as a jndi datasource you can use the following configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" ref="datasourceJNDIName" />
    <property name="defaultObject" ref="fallBackDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- fall back datasource if JNDI look up of main datasource fails -->
<bean id="fallBackDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" ref="datasourceJNDIName-2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks it solves the first part. Do we have an option to check if defaultDataSource has come back up and connect to it?

Comment: hmmm, you can create a table lets say `TDBVERSION` which contains only one row whether the database is backup or not. and by quering the `TDBVERSION` your system would be aware wheter it is using the backup or not.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of tricks have to be done on MySQL side not on the webapp. MySQL cluster for instance can handle this.

More infos here:

-http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/

-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Cluster

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so, have a look here -> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource . Build a custom implementation that override the method getConnection() and getConnection(String username, String password). Surroud them by catching SQLException, and if occurs, choose the other datasource.

Comment: I know it is wrong.. but our current architecture forces us to have the above mechanism :( We are stuck with the old architecture and can't move immediately!!